# PHP Difference between $this-> Class Calls

Tags: php, wordpress, this

I am not sure why, but i am getting all confused over a function with Wordpress.

```
if (!empty($this->participant_id)) : ?>    
  <?php // output any validation errors
 $this->print_errors(); ?>

  <?php // print the form header
  $this->print_form_head()
  ?>
```

I am trying to find what creates the `print_form_head()` within a Wordpress Plugin.  I am using PHPStorm as an editor and there is a difference between the two of the 3 $this calls above.

```
$this->participant_id
```

The above puts the participant_id in bold

`$this->print_form_head()` AND `$this->print_errors()`

Are not bold, and just normal font, the other difference is with the `()` at the end.

Can someone explain what the difference is, as this might help me find the form_head part of the code ?

**UPDATE**
As you can see, I put Function above, as that is what I thought it was, but being new to Wordpress and there Plugins I wanted to ensure i was still not missing something.  Hence the question, and some people feel the need to make me down for double checking...

Comment: You really should start with learning PHP and programmation in general... It's not a place for total beginners. And to answer your question: `$this->something` is a property, and `$this->something()` is a method...

Comment: @vard Thank you, and I thought I knew PHP, but Wordpress and different plugs, and how they are built is a tad confusing.  I always thought form_head() was a function, but as i could not find it, I wanted to double check, as Wordpress is new to me.  But thank you.  PS, thanks for voting me down ;)

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a tutorial of OOP in PHP first. You can also find quick references in the PHP [documentation of objects and classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) (but it cannot replace a good tutorial).

Comment: This is a great tutorial on php class basics. I think its the best I've seen at explaining php classes. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Comment: @axiac From the look at some of these plugins, I'm not the only one ;-)  But i just wanted to make sure i was on the right track.  As i said, Wordpress plugins are not built the same.

Comment: Also, in order to explain what you want, we would need to see the entire class that you are referencing with the $this call.

Comment: @Hanoncs There are so many files i would not know where to begin, but as I could not find the function, and being new to Wordpress, and there plugins, i thought i would just ask to just double check.

Comment: @AndrewWalker As for your edit, we don't want to let you down, we just want to give you up some insights about your question - you could have found the solution by yourself as this is basics of OOP (nothing specific to Wordpress here) and there is plenty of tutorials out there about that. Telling you to read some ressources before starting programming is a good advice, not an insult.

Comment: @vard My question was not about OOP, but how Wordpress dealt with it.  AS I said, I thought it was a function, but i cannot find it anywhere within the 20 odd files that come with the plugin.  So marking me down I did not take as an insult, I accept perhaps i worded my question wrong.  But I am not new to OOP or PHP.  Only Wordpress and it confused me why i could not find a function where normally i would be able to find.

Comment: @AndrewWalker, the only way to do that would be to search through all of your plugin files. The code you have included isn't part of core WordPress.

Comment: @AndrewWalker The way you stated your question is "why my IDE is showing this in bold and this not" - that didn't sound like you knew what OOP means. If you do, I'm a bit confused about what you're asking exactly. If you know what a method is, then you didn't found it in the class declaration? Does this class inherit on any other class?

Comment: @vard Sorry, only just seen this.  The classes are loaded with a loader, but the reason I could not find the function was because of where it was placed, which is in the class file called Shortcode.  Which would have been the last place I would have thought it would  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are being highlighted differently because they are [different parts of a Class/Object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

`participant_id` is a [class member **variable** called a "property"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

`print_form_head()` and `print_errors()` are class-contained **functions**, and are called "methods".

The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called **from within an object context**. `$this` is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

Comment: Down votes without an explanation are useless, as both I and the original poster are unable to learn from any mistakes I may have made. I would love the opportunity to fix any issues in my answer, if the down-voter would be so kind as to explain where I was incorrect.

Comment: thank you for this.  Do I then assume, if the function is not within the plugin files, it's a secondary object ?  Or more that I missing a file which this function is held ?

Comment: The class has to exist somewhere. It's not a part of core WordPress...so it has to exist in a plugin somewhere. You should be able to use your editor to search through all plugin files at the same time. I would search specifically for `function print_form_head`